# Can I simply call a constructor on allocated memory, instead of placement new?

Tags: c++

So I have a container-like pool class, which is basically a wrapper to an `std::vector<char*> blocks`, where memory is allocated by doing:

```
char* block = new char[elementSize * blockSize];
blocks.push_back( block );
```

This pool has a `void* get_addr( std::size_t n )` which returns the memory address of element n.

I know, that I can construct a new object there by doing:
`new( get_addr(n) ) Object( args )`;
But I can also do it this way:

```
// Create a supplimentary method
T& get( std::size_t n ) { return *static_cast<T*>( get_addr(n) ); }
// ... 
// ...
// and an example usage, where Object is arbitrary
Object& obj = pool.get( 10 );
obj = Object( args );
```

I've tried both, and of course the placement new method works, but so does the second method of constructing too.
And so I'm interested, in whether are there any restrictions on why I shouldn't use the second way, or is it safe to do so.

Comment: And what about `obj = Object( args );` // This is the method I'm asking about.

Comment: That would create a new object, and assign it to `obj`. Quite a few operations...

Comment: Why would you want to? Placement new is the syntax for doing what you want to do, why avoid using it?

Comment: If `Object` has the default `operator=` and any of its member variables has an `operator=` that does more than just write operations on the object's  memory then it's unsafe. But yeah, placement new only calls a constructor on pre-allocated memory, whereas your method first calls copy constructor and then `operator=` and is possibly unsafe, so why not just use placement new?

Comment: mattnewport, well, because I'd like to make using that element as simple as `obj = Object(); obj.foo()` instead of `new( get_addr(n) ) Object(); obj = pool.get(n); obj.foo();`
Thanks for warnings though, looks like I'll be using placement new then.

Comment: If you want to work with raw memory then this could be if interest for you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer

Comment: Daniel Jour, thanks, I'll definitely take a look. Already doing it.

Comment: Did you mean `Object &obj = pool.get(10);` ?  (It's still UB but not so egregiously awful as your original code)

Comment: Matt McNabb, oh, yes, it was a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's completely unsafe to do so, as you are assigning to an object which is uninitialized. This will break pretty much any complex type.

Placement new is literally calling the constructor on allocated memory - that's it's job and purpose. The question you're asking simply doesn't make sense. "How can I use language feature X without using X?". You *must* construct objects before doing shit with them.